# SAS do-loop question for creating SAS data subcategories conditionally

Tags: automation, sas, do-loops

```
data period;
set output.Sample_Y_n_deln;
if delnum >= 181 and delnum <= 184;
run;

data period2;
set output.Sample_Y_n_deln;
if delnum >= 185 and delnum <= 188;
run;

data period3;
set output.Sample_Y_n_deln;
if delnum >= 189 and delnum <= 192;
run;
```

Is there a way to automate this using some kind of loop? That point of this exercise is to get quarterly time slices for my data set based on delnum which is the date in a numeric format specific for this set.

I have heard of proc timeseries which seems applicable on first glance but I do not know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use formats, but it depends on what you're doing next. If you want summaries by the period for example this works fine. There are also multiple ways to use the format in various other procs and data steps.

```
proc format;
value delnum_fmt
181 - 184 = "Period 1"
185 - 188 = "Period 2"
189 - 192 = "Period 3"
other = "Outside Period of Interest"
;
run;

proc freq data=output.sample_y_n_deln;
table delnum;
format delnum delnum_fmt.;
run;
```

[Here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf) is a good introductory reference on formats in SAS, and of course the [documentation reference](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/leforinforref/n11m54nggvjybhn1w2a8mbczw04q.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are going to replicate your data many times.  It might be better to instead just add columns to be able to quickly filter to the sets you want.

If the periods are overlapping add a separate column for each period.

```
data periods;
  set output.Sample_Y_n_deln;
  period1 = (181 <= delnum 184);
  period2 = (185 <= delnum 188);
  period3 = (189 <= delnum 182);
run;
```

The you can use the new variables in WHERE clauses in your analysis steps.

```
proc means data=periods ;
    where period1 ;
   ...
```

If the periods do not overlap then you can just have a single variable with the PERIOD identifier instead.

```
data periods;
  set output.Sample_Y_n_deln;
  if (181 <= delnum 184) then period=1;
  else if (185 <= delnum 188) then period=2;
  else if (189 <= delnum 182) then period=3;
run;
```